# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded inside a functional component using UseState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm a beginner to react and have been trying for hours to debug and resolve this issue without any avail.

I'm using Ant Design tables which contains a "footer" api that return all the values after the data has been filtered. These values are then passed to a function (handledFilteredObj) which then pushes the passed values (currentPageData) to a temporary object. This temporary object is then set to the csvData state variable using it's setter method.

However, when I use the code as mentioned, my app throws this error:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Here is my code:

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

import { Space, Table } from "antd"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { CSVLink, CSVDownload } from "react-csv";
import styles from "../HeaderComponent/DashBoardComponent/Dashboard.module.css";

const TransactionTableComponent = (props) => {

    let f_obj = [];

    const [filteredInfo, setFilteredInfo] = useState(null)
    const [csvData, setCsvData] = useState("nothing")
    const csvDataRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        setFilteredInfo({});
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
    }, [filteredInfo])

    useEffect(() => {
    }, [csvData])

    const handleChange = (pagination, filters) => {
        setFilteredInfo(filters);
    }

    const handledFilteredObj = (currentPageData) => {
        f_obj = [];
        if (currentPageData.length > 0) {
            currentPageData.forEach(element => {
                debugger
                console.log(element)
                f_obj.push(element)
            })
        }
        setCsvData(f_obj)
        return null
    }

    const transactionTableColumns = [
        {
            title: 'Transaction ID',
            dataIndex: 'TransactionId',
            key: 'TransactionId',
            width: 150,
            sorter: (a, b) => a.TransactionId - b.TransactionId,

        },
        {
            title: 'Transaction Amount',
            dataIndex: 'TransactionAmount',
            key: 'TransactionAmount',
            width: 150,
            sorter: (a, b) => a.TransactionAmount - b.TransactionAmount,
            ellipsis: true,
        },
        {
            title: 'Date',
            dataIndex: 'TransactionDate',
            key: 'TransactionDate',
            width: 150,
        },
        {
            title: "TransactionType",
            dataIndex: "TransactionType",
            key: "TransactionType",
            filters: [
                { text: "Deposit", value: "DEPOSIT" },
                { text: "Withdrawl", value: "WITHDRAWL" },
                { text: "Bill Payment", value: "BILLPAYMENT" }
            ],
            onFilter: (value, record) => record.TransactionType.includes(value)
        },
        {
            title: 'Transaction Time',
            dataIndex: 'TransactionTime',
            width: 150,
            key: 'TransactionTime',
            sorter: (a, b) => a.TransactionTime < b.TransactionTime,
        },
        {
            title: 'CNIC',
            dataIndex: 'RiderCNIC',
            width: 150,
            key: 'RiderCNIC',
        }
    ];

    return (
        <Space direction='vertical'>
            <Table
                className={styles.RiderTable}
                columns={transactionTableColumns}
                dataSource={props.transactionTableData}
                size={'middle'}
                scroll={{ y: 240 }}
                onChange={handleChange}
                footer={(currentPageData) =>
                    handledFilteredObj(currentPageData)
                }
            />

            <CSVLink data={csvData} className="btn btn-primary">
                Extract Data
            </CSVLink>
        </Space>
    )
}

export default TransactionTableComponent
```

Here is what I have tried. Please note that the code is shortened for brevity.

**Passed an event to the handledFilteredObj() method** along with the data so as to stop propagation using event.stopPropagation but it always found event undefined.

```
const handledFilteredObj = (event, currentPageData) => {
        f_obj = [];
        if (currentPageData.length > 0) {
            currentPageData.forEach(element => {
                debugger
                console.log(element)
                f_obj.push(element)
            })
        }
        setCsvData(f_obj)
        event.stopPropagation()
        return null
    }

//inside jsx
//...more code
<Table
                className={styles.RiderTable}
                columns={transactionTableColumns}
                dataSource={props.transactionTableData}
                size={'middle'}
                scroll={{ y: 240 }}
                onChange={handleChange}
                footer={(currentPageData, event) =>
                    handledFilteredObj(currentPageData, event)
                }
            />
```

**Using a scope variable** using *let* keyword but this variable's data never changed even though it changed within the function when I consoled it.

```
//declaring the data variable:
let data = [];

const handledFilteredObj = (currentPageData) => {
        f_obj = [];
        if (currentPageData.length > 0) {
            currentPageData.forEach(element => {
                debugger
                console.log(element)
                f_obj.push(element)
            })
        }
        data = f_obj   //.....set data var to f_obj
        return null
    }

            <CSVLink data={data} className="btn btn-primary">
                Extract Data
            </CSVLink>
```

Comment: could you put this code in a codesandbox for a better reproduction?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xbcnwf